# Spring Cloud Contract for AMQP - autowiring issues with RabbitTemplate

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-amqp, spring-cloud-contract

I am trying to run a contract test for Spring AMQP using Spring Cloud Contract. However I am running into an issue with autowiring of the RabbitTemplate. In my Base Test class below, the autowired RabbitTemplate expects a ConnectionFactory with valid connection details (host and port of RabbitMQ brokers). Since contract tests are not expected to actually connect to the message broker, there is no host and port supplied to the connection factory in the test env.

I get the error

```
org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.net.UnknownHostException: ${queue.hosts}: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:71)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:614)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:240)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1810)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1784)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.send(RabbitTemplate.java:864)
```

Is the RabbitTemplate supposed to be mocked? I tried it but even that isn't working. 
Also tried passing mock ConnectionFactory to the actual RabbitTemplate but it tries to get a real connection from the mock factory.
How do you get around the problem that it tries to make an actual connection?

Base Test Class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = QueueConfiguration.class)
@AutoConfigureMessageVerifier
    public class CreateNotificationBase {

    private String message;

    @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;


    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        client = new ChangeNotificationClient();
        message = client.buildChangeNotificationMessage();
    }

    protected void onUserCreation() {
    rabbitTemplate.send("change_notification_exchange",
            RoutingKey.CHANGE_NOTIFICATION_KEY.getName(),
            org.springframework.amqp.core.MessageBuilder.withBody(message.getBytes()).build());
    }
}
```

Contract Definition

```
label: user_create
input:
  triggeredBy: onUserCreation()
outputMessage:
  sentTo: change_notification_exchange
  body: ''' {"data":["....."jsonapi":{"version":"1.0"}} '''
```

Auto-generated Test

```
public class CreateTest extends CreateNotificationBase {

    @Inject ContractVerifierMessaging contractVerifierMessaging;
    @Inject ContractVerifierObjectMapper contractVerifierObjectMapper;

    @Test
    public void validate_create() throws Exception {
        // when:
            onUserCreation();

        // then:
            ContractVerifierMessage response = contractVerifierMessaging.receive("change_notification_exchange");
            assertThat(response).isNotNull();
        // and:
            Object responseBody = (contractVerifierObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(response.getPayload()));
                // assertions
            ;
    }

}
```

Comment: cost too much time to reproduce your issue. can your share your project at github.

Comment: Have you set `stubrunner.amqp.enabled` to `true` ? (https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/reference/html/project-features.html#features-messaging-stub-runner-amqp-adding)

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak Yes it is set to true. Should the rabbitTemplate in my example be mocked or real?

Comment: It should be a spy. Can you run the test with -Ddebug=true to see the autoconfig report confirms that stub messages for amqp is used?

Comment: Ran `gradle contractTest --debug` and `gradle contractTest -Ddebug=true` but not getting any debug logs.

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak How is the RabbitTemplate here instantiated https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/blob/master/tests/samples-messaging-amqp/src/main/java/com/example/AmqpMessagingApplication.java ? That might give me some hints.

Comment: It's in the configuration class marked as a bean, then it's wrapped in a spy by spring cloud contract